# How to instanciate a rail model within erb form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

Is it possible to instantiate a rails model (knowing its id) within an erb form.
I was doing it using haml as below and now wants to use erb forms.

```
- business_trip_request = BusinessTripRequest.find(id)
```

Comment: The same way, but using erb syntax. But why would you want to do this? The action method should create data destined for use in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should not. It is generally not good practice to violate the MVC structure. The view should not be accessing the database. You should let the controller load instance variables from the models, and let the view focus on just displaying it.

If you must do it, then try this in an html.erb file:

```
<% business_trip_request = BusinessTripRequest.find(id) %>
```

To display the id and the name fields(eg.):

```
<%= business_trip_request.id %> <br />
<%= business_trip_request.name %> <br />
```

Comment: ok. I am currently trying to tie together rails with ruote (a workflow engine). and an easy way is to to instantiate a given model know that it is next on the ruote work item list.